# Mercurial - determine which repository a changeset was pushed to?

Tags: mercurial, merge, hg-log

If you `hg push` changeset A into repository `myapp-v1` and then do an `hg pull` and `hg merge` to merge that into `myapp-v2`, is there a way in the `myapp-v2` repository to identify that the changeset was originally checked into `myapp-v1`?

Comment: I think you should use the dedicated Mercurial terms in your question, what do you exactly mean by "check in" ? I suppose `push` by the looks of it. I also think `merge` has nothing to do with what you're describing. Can you provide a list of commands related to your question to clarify things ?

Comment: In principle no, this is not possible because of the distributed nature of Mercurial. There are no unique identifiers of repositories. What you could do I guess is maintain a central pushlog so that you can find out where a changeset was first pushed to, but you’ll have to build such a system yourself for your specific use-case, and configure it for each repository that you want to participate in it, there is not any kind of generic functionality for this.

Comment: Instead of inquiring about this very specific solution, can you describe what specific problem you are trying to solve? Why do you want to identify this? What will you use the information for? That way it would be easier to suggest a solution that suits your needs.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: There is no specific reason.  At times it is useful to know where a changeset was originally pushed to.  It can help gain some context as to the purpose of the changeset.

Comment: @Marcus Then, what Lazy Badger said :).

Comment: "purpose of the changeset" must be in commit message and (if branch-per-action policy used) in branch-name. Period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. DVCS is DVCS and **commited** changeset haven't any origin-data after transfer to other clones

Workaround - permanent attributes of each changeset are

- branch
- author name

you can use these signs